# Как в Хроме отключить миниатюры под поиском?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, apple

Есть ли возможность отключить эти миниатюры?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не касается темы программирования/администрирования.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Установите расширение [Hide Most Visited Pages Reloaded](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-most-visited-pages-r/dhphmpoekpoecdbjeionimpiceigkeil/related).

Comment: То что нужно. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Создай своею тему: https://www.themebeta.com/chrome-theme-creator-online.html#.

Там уже сможешь отключить эти миниатюры.

Comment: Точно смогу? Так, с наскоку не нашел опции